# How to disable shortcut for an Automator script?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, automator

A few weeks ago I wrote a short script with the Automator to get familiar with it.
I found a website which explained how to set up a primitive script to start the screensaver and define a shortcut to start it. I chose `cmd + L` to activate the script and it worked fine.

Now I want to disable the shortcut and delete the script. The problem is, that I forgot how and where I defined the shortcut. It is not listet in the *system preference -> keyboard* section. Unfortunately I can't find the website with the how to or an equivalent description.

Any suggestions for my awkward situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the shortcut and not the service go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` and *make sure that in the right pane services is selected*, I think that might have been your issue. The just un-click the check box next to your listed service.

I've had an issue recently where services aren't showing up in the services pane, to fix this just copy the service to your desktop from `~/Library/Services` and delete the service in the Library directory, then paste the service back in again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` and the shortcut isn't listed there.
In the `~/Library/Services/` there is just a hidden file named `.localized`. Should I delete it?

Comment: If there isn't a `.workflow` in that folder then you haven't created a service, you've created something else. Automator stores all you're services there. Another option would try typing `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -flush` into the terminal and pressing enter. That will reload the services, then check again.

Comment: Flushing the pbs didn't solve my problem either. Now I removed the executable script and if I push `cmd + l` an error messages pops up whichs says: `The program can't be found'

Comment: What format was the script?

Comment: I think it was `.app`  file.

Comment: Is it listed under `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`?

Comment: No it's not. The odd thing is that I reconfigured the command `cmd + L` to another application ( to open the lexicon ). Maybe it would then override the other configuration but for my surprise it didn't work. The command `cmd + L` is still locking for the app I deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help much further, reinstall OS X? (That was a joke)

Comment: Hehe, a good one! 
Any way thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using Automator to create a service will place the service in **~/Library/Services**. You can delete the service from here. Deleting it will also delete assigned keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the ~/Library/Services/ there is just a hidden file named .localized. Should I delete it?